# Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build Exception caught: basedir src/main/docker does not exist

Tags: docker, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-cloud

Deploy `Spring Cloud` project with `docker`, some code in the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::plugin[] -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when i run the command: `mvn package docker:build`, it throws the error:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) @ eureka-server ---
[INFO] Using authentication suppliers: [ConfigFileRegistryAuthSupplier]
[INFO] Copying /Users/eureka-server/target/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -> /Users/eureka-server/target/docker/eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.728 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-15T20:51:07+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/361M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) on project eureka-server: Exception caught: basedir src/main/docker does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

my project has this file `src/main/docker`, how to solve it?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. Is this problem solved?

Comment: @SiddharthaThota, yes, please look at the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add project path to the dockerDirectory:

```
<dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
```

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::plugin[] -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```